# How to update just some of properties in Edit action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

**Preface**:

I'm working on a project using **MVC 5**. We've built up our `database` from which our `model` is created. Then, we've added the `Controllers` and `Views` using Scaffolding. However in the Views we've omitted some of the properties (they should not be shown to the users).

**Problem**:
In the actions like Edit, as I hit the save button (to update the model) I encounter an `exception` and I think it requires me to provide the value of all the properties.

Please let me know how can I update just some of the properties (shown in the view)? 
Please note that I need a solution as general as possible, so as to be able to use it in many Edit actions that I have in this project (Indeed this is the hard part).

**Code**:
The following are some of the codes that I think are most related to this question:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AreaCode,Tels,Address")] Area area)
    {//Area has many more properties (defined as required in the database) and I just need to update
        //these : AreaCode,Tels,Address
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(area).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Detector = new SelectList(db.Detectors, "DetectorCode", "detectorName", area.Detector);
    ViewBag.Grade = new SelectList(db.Grades, "Gradeid", "GradeName", area.Grade);
    return View(area);
}
```

**SS**:

[image]

**Answers expressed in a simple way are highly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Get your object to update from the database, and sets your model with the old value of properties

public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "AreaCode,Tels,Address")] Area area)
    {

```
YourDbContext _db= new YourDbContext();
Area oldArea = _db.Areas.Where(x => x.ID == area.ID).FirstOrDefault();


  // Bind others properties marked with required from database 
   area.x = oldArea.x;
   area.y = oldArea.y;


if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Entry(area).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
ViewBag.Detector = new SelectList(db.Detectors, "DetectorCode", "detectorName", area.Detector);
ViewBag.Grade = new SelectList(db.Grades, "Gradeid", "GradeName", area.Grade);
return View(area);
```

}